# Error in DeepMask's Pytorch Code

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent, semantic-segmentation

I’m currently trying to implement Deepmask ([Link to FAIR's Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.06204.pdf)) using Pytorch, so far I have defined the Joint Loss Function, and the model’s learn-able parameters and the forward pass.

I was working on the training phase, and as the paper says that *training must be done in an alternative back-propagation fashion across the two branches*, I have written the code for the same.

But there is some problem with training, I tried to train the model with a fake data-set (a randomly generated data-set), for minibatches other than the first mini-batch the loss of the model is turning out to be **nan**.

What could be the reason for this **nan** loss?

[Link to current version of my code](https://github.com/mejanvijay/DeepMask-Pytorch/blob/master/DeepMask-Pytorch-Implementation.ipynb)

Comment: I would check your loss function again, perhaps you're doing division by zero somewhere.

Comment: I have gone through the loss function, and I can't find any variable being in denominator. Thanks for the suggestion.